# How To Create Custom UIWebView Pages

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

Not a cry out for some coding issue. Just need to know what would be the right strategy to make a custom webview.

I am using `NSXMLParser` and i have successfully parsed a wordpress blog to in a tableview with thumbnails, titles, and other labels.

I have also successfully created a `UIWebView` that shows blog posts in the following way:

[image: Output]

What i want is to have a custom look starting from title, image and then the blog post written content. For example, Mashable's iPhone app, that shows blog posts but they doesn't look like the generic uiwebview posts

[image: What i want]

1. As i am already parsing much content in the app. Do i need to create labels and images etc. in a view controller and pull the day from the website to fill them.
2. Or is there some other way i can make the UIWebView to show only the items from the blog posts that i want.

Comment: The Mashable app just uses a mobile website fo their website - What do you want to achieve with the custom UIWebView? You can still parse data into it, but if you using wordpress - look into WPTouch

Comment: @JeffKranenburg I want to have a look and feel of a mobile site inside the uiwebview, although the site i am using does not have any mobile site. How can i do that?

Comment: @JeffKranenburg is there way if may the UiWebView can only display specific content from the html (for example, title, image and written content) in the right font size and leave the sidebars and other stuff.

Comment: Sorry no you cannot. The website file is essentially a flat file. Even though you will see just text - it may be generated from a database. This means there is no telling how you would have to parse it. Also if they change anything it will break your app - so it is a risky path.

Comment: @JeffKranenburg So what abt all these javascripts and stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString and innerHtml etc.? is it not related to my problem?

Comment: Yup that can work, but you would need to know what you are looking for. Like with Javascript you would need to know what the names of the classes are that you referencing to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Mashable site is a mixture of a mobile web site (i.e. a web site that detects mobile devices, and delivers a variation of the HTML ideally suited for mobile devices) and a mobile app that is basically providing a standard `UIWebView`, a custom tool bar (with email, tweet, fb links, etc), and ads at the bottom.

It's not prudent to try to parse a standard web site to render a mobile-friendly rendition. You should start, first, with a proper mobile-friendly web site. (As evidence that this is what Mashable did, go to their web site in the iPhone Safari, and you'll notice that you enjoy much of the look and feel there, too.) Then, you can decide whether you also want to deploy an app to facilitate the navigation of this web site from the mobile device.

Personally, I believe that an app which is merely a thin wrapper around a `UIWebView` that navigates within some mobile-friendly web site is not terribly compelling. You need to offer the user some significant value proposition, something above and beyond the typical mobile web site. You have to justify the time and effort that the user went through to install your app. Just because you like them in your customized ecosystem of your native app, doesn't mean that it makes sense for them. You need to make it a worthwhile engagement for the user. (And with no offense to Mashable, theirs is probably a poor example. It doesn't feel like there's enough there. Some decent news apps, such as *Bloomberg, The Economist,* and maybe even the *WSJ* or *NY Times* might be a better example of a custom property offering enough UX benefits to justify using their apps.)

Setting aside this broader question, you asked a few tactical questions:

- To get that customized title bar, you just create the controls to render that toolbar in your storyboard or NIB. Nothing terribly sophisticated there.
- To only show particular web pages in your `UIWebView`, you should make your controller conform to [`UIWebViewDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), set your controller to be the `delegate` of the `UIWebView`, and implement [`shouldStartLoadWithRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIWebViewDelegate/webView%3ashouldStartLoadWithRequest%3anavigationType%3a).

Comment: So is it ok if instead of just showing the mobile site inside uiwebview, i parse and show results in a viewcontroller the way i want ???

Comment: If you have access to the source code of the website, than yes. If it is generated, you cannot really leave out the code that easy.

Comment: @Rob Yes you are right. Also, if i parse and show results of each post, i don't know how i would handle the links inside the post when the user clicks on them

Comment: @Rob right. In my case, the links are working without any extra function

Comment: @Rob is there any way i can catch specific content from the html like (title, image and written content) and the uiwebview can neglect the sidebars and other stuff.?

Comment: @Jessica you can, but it's a non-trivial problem. To do this in the generalized situation is pretty complicated. If you're doing this for a single third-party web site, it's a little ugly, but you can often examine the HTML, identify patterns, a parse the HTML on the basis of your findings and thus it is not nearly as bad as the generalized solution. If you're doing this for your own site, this would be silly, as you would be better off just deploying a mobile-version of your web site that does not deliver the extra content in certain situations (such as mobile web browser).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21902/discussion-between-rob-and-jessica)